# using synchronized with LiveData value throws compile error about type inference in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, synchronized, android-livedata

I have a Room Entity that has a field that may be updated from concurrent locations. So to avoid interleaving, I thought I should do

```
synchronized(dogLiveData.value){
  dao.update(dog)
}
```

but Android Studio is complaining that *"Type inference failed. Please try to specify type arguments explicitly."* Any advice on how I might fix this?

Comment: Just replace dogLiveData.value with dogLiveData::java.class or cast it to LiveData <Dog>

Comment: @salyela have you got solution?